# JS Asynchronous execution is causing pain

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am developing a backend server code with NodeJS. What the code does is, periodically connect to a REST API, request updates and then write to my database.

I have no way of getting delta of the data from the API, so I drop my collection from MongoDB and then just insert the newly pulled data.

I implemented promises to make sure that the dependent methods are executed only after the previous methods resolve. This however doesn't seem to work as I anticipated.

So, I drop the collection and insert, this works. But the following method seems to execute before the new data is populated. It sometime works, when I have some new `console.log` statements which seems to induce a slight delay ever so slightly to make it all work.

`setTimeout` function didn't seem to help. Any suggestions?

Here is a sanitized version of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ppbfrozg/

```
var request = require("request");
var q = require('q');

function authenticate() {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(body).token);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}


function getData(token) {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(body).token);

  });

  return deferred.promise;
}


function insertDataInMongo(a) {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost/myDB';
  var token = a[1];
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) return deferred.reject(new Error(err))
    console.log("connected for insert");


    var apiData = JSON.parse(a[0]).data;

    if (JSON.parse(a[0]).data) {


      db.collection('MediaData').insert(apiData);
      console.log("Records Inserted");
    } else {

      db.collection('Details').drop();
      db.collection('Details').insert(JSON.parse(a[0]));

      console.log("Records Inserted");
    }

    deferred.resolve(token);

  });

  return deferred.promise;
}


function getMedia(dataContext) {

  var deferred = q.defer();

  var cursor = dataContext[0];
  var token = dataContext[1];

  if (cursor !== null) {
    console.log("Inside cursor not null");

    cursor.forEach(function(data) {
      insertDataInMongo(data);
    })
  }

  return deferred.promise;
}


function check(array, attr, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i][attr] === value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function get_value(array, attr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i].hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
      return array[i][attr];
    }
  }
}


function getNames(token) {

  var deferred = q.defer();

  var MongoClient2 = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost/myDB';

  console.log("going to get Data");

  MongoClient2.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) return deferred.reject(new Error(err));
    console.log("connected for select");

    var data = db.collection('Details').find();
    var dataContext = [data, token, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null];

    deferred.resolve(dataContext);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}


function convertDate(date) {
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  var dd = (date.getDate() - 3).toString();

  var mmChars = mm.split('');
  var ddChars = dd.split('');

  return yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1] ? mm : "0" + mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1] ? dd : "0" + ddChars[0]);
}


authenticate()
  .then(getData)
  .then(insertDataInMongo)
  .then(getNames)
  .then(getMedia);
```

Comment: It's impossible to help without some code

Comment: Will post some. Trying to sanitize..

Comment: Damn you posted a lot of code. I've no idea about MongoDb, but inside function `insertDataInMongo` you are calling `db.collection('MediaData').insert(apiData);` and then calling `deferred.resolve()` without any wait, which implies that the call is synchronous. Is that correct?

Comment: There is an issue with you `insertDataInMongo` function. You are making DB calls like(`db.collection('Details').drop(); db.collection('Details').insert(JSON.parse(a[0]));`) and not waiting for those operations to complete. Hence, that function gets resolved before those DB operations are completed.

Comment: @Maria Ines Parnisari: As far as I have researched, there is a no wait in Javascript. Something that comes close is the settimeout function, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Hannan how can I make it wait?

Comment: See @Hannan's comment, which is exactly what I meant.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for those Mongo apis, see if they return a promise or take a callback function as a parameter, and modify the location of `deferred.resolve` accordingly. As it is now, your code is not waiting for the inserts to finish.

Comment: @SAS ill post an example in separate answer so code is more clear

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) helps to get a better understanding of promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Let me know if any issue.

```
function insertDataInMongo(a) {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost/myDB';
  var token = a[1];
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) return deferred.reject(new Error(err))
    console.log("connected for insert");

    var apiData = JSON.parse(a[0]).data;
    if (JSON.parse(a[0]).data) {
      db.collection('MediaData').insert(apiData, function(){
        console.log("Records Inserted");
        return deferred.resolve(token);
      });
    } else {
      db.collection('Details').drop(function(error, result){//Callback function that executes after drop operation has completed.
        if(error){
          return deferred.reject(error);//Reject the promise if there was an error
        }
        db.collection('Details').insert(JSON.parse(a[0]), function(err, res){//Callback function that executes after insert operation has completed.
          if(err){
            return deferred.reject(err);//Reject the promise if there was an error
          }
          console.log("Records Inserted");
          return deferred.resolve(token);
        });
      });
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It almost worked! 

 I am getting the following error now:

        MongoError: Invalid Operation, No operations in bulk

Comment: This link should help you. https://github.com/toymachiner62/node-mongo-seeds/issues/6

Comment: data is being inserted now.. so yes it worked! but can you help with the error above?

Comment: I did find that link. I think I am inserting an empty array at the end, that is causing the issue. Tried to Skip inserting it by using an ifcondition like:

        if (apiData !== {} )
{
       //then insert data
}

Answer (score 0):

From what I see from nodeJS driver API for MongoDB :
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

hint : db.collection.drop is asynchronous, so you have to use a callback with it

```
db.collection('Details').drop(function(err, result){
    // Do anything AFTER you dropped your collection
}
```

but since you are using promises, you should use something like that:

```
authenticate()
.then(getData)
.then(db.collection('Details').drop)
.then(insertDataInMongo)
.then(getNames)
.then(getMedia);
```

or if you want to really keep the same code format :

```
function dropCollectionInMongo() {
    db.collection('Details').drop()
}
authenticate()
.then(getData)
.then(dropCollectionInMongo)
.then(insertDataInMongo)
.then(getNames)
.then(getMedia);
```